# Numpy array ndmin behavior for empty array

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
np.array([], ndmin=2)
```

The resulting array has shape (1, 0). But why not (0, 0), if the input array has length 0? Is there a better way to create an array of shape (0, 0) than explicitely call `np.zeros((0, 0))`?

Comment: There's nothing *preventing* that array from having a shape of `(0, 0)`, verify for yourself by assigning that shape to it, or using `reshape`.  The behavior of the constructor is to append `1s` until the number of dimensions has been satisfied.

Comment: Why do you prefer (0,0) over (1,0)?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for `numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

> **ndmin : int, optional** -- Specifies the minimum number of dimensions that the resulting array should have. **Ones will be pre-pended to the shape as needed to meet this requirement**

You're giving it a shape (0,) array-like, so it prepends a 1 to make the shape size 2.

`np.zeros((0, 0))` is fine.

Comment: "Ones will be pre-pended to the shape as **needed to meet this requirement**" - why is it even needed?

Comment: It doesn't treat the `[]` case special. `np.array( np.ones(n), ndmin=2)` becomes (1,n) shape regardless whether `n` is 0 or 10.  Consistency like that is nice.

Comment: @steam_engine `[]` is a shape `(0,)` array-like, and you tell it that your requirement is a shape `(x,y)` array-like, so it appends a 1 before the 0 to give you an array with shape `(1,0)`.